# Why did the students laugh at the Walt Whitman quote?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021, eternals

In *Eternals* (2021), Black Knight says to students in the class room:

> In this broad earth of ours, Amid the measureless grossness and  the
> slag, Enclosed and safe within its central heart, Nestles the  seed of
> perfection. *[Students laugh]*

Why did the students laugh at the Walt Whitman quote?

Comment: It sounds like it might be mocking the "seed of perfection" part; as in, people are flawed by nature.

Comment: I mean it's probably the funniest Walt Whitman line. Apart from that one about leaves of grass. Leaves aren't made of grass, Walt, you nutter!

Comment: There's also the modern connotation of "slag" and the mention of seed. They're youthful students, no doubt with the usual preoccupations present at that age.

Comment: @JiminyCricket.You know, I probably would have thought of that one until I read that line of yours, but yeah, good point.

Comment: According to this article https://collider.com/details-fans-missed-from-eternals/#walt-whitman-predicted-the-celestials, its actually a foreshadowing of the eternals rising from the earth's core(central heart).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I think it fair to call blades of grass “leaves”; what about maize?

Comment: @shanu And being students, they’d already seen a Bittorrent copy of the movie three weeks ago, so they got the reference.